# Si tu pouvais ou Si tu pourrais

Tags: conditionnel

Bonjour, doit-on dire :

**Si tu pourrais aller chercher de l'eau, ce serait cool.**

ou bien

**Si tu pouvais aller chercher de l'eau, ce serait cool**

J'ai lu que le *si* introduisant une interrogation n'est pas concerné par le conditionnel.

Merci.

Comment: I don’t have time to write a thorough answer yet, but see: https://www.laits.utexas.edu/tex/pdf/tac3.pdf

Comment: Je me demande si vous ne confondez pas le subjonctif et le conditionnel ? "tu pourrais" n'est pas un subjonctif présent mais un conditionnel présent.

Comment: Modifications faites. Merci.

Comment: Je suis surpris que personne n'en ait encore parlé, mais "*Tu pourrais aller chercher de l'eau ? Ce serait cool.*" est une formulation correcte. À mon sens, c'est pour ça que "*Si tu pourrais*" peut sonner familier. Le conditionnel sert ici de formule de politesse.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dans une proposition qui indique une condition et introduite par "si", la règle est de ne jamais utiliser le conditionnel mais l'indicatif. On simplifie parfois cette règle par "les si n'aiment pas les rai".

La forme correcte est donc:

> Si tu pouvais aller chercher de l'eau, ce serait cool

*Si tu pourrais* dans une condition peut être entendu en français familier, mais c'est une faute qui "fera mal aux oreilles", et considérée comme typique d'un usage incorrect du français, ou d'une faute faite par les enfants (par exemple dans le roman "La Guerre des boutons", il y a la célèbre phrase *si j'aurais su, j'aurais pas venu* mise avec humour dans la bouche d'un petit enfant).

Par contre, dans une proposition qui indique une question en discours indirect et introduite par "si", le conditionnel est possible.

> Je me demandais si tu pourrais aller chercher de l'eau.

Comment: Parfait, merci beaucoup !

Comment: La règle s'écrit: Les scies n'aiment pas les raies. C'est une jeu mnémonique  de poissons, comme si les poissons scies n'aimaient pas les raies. PVI les poissons scies sont une espèce de raie :)

Comment: What would have been the correct phrase in "La Guerre des boutons"? _Si j'avais su, je n'étais pas venu_?

Answer (score 4):

Les deux s'entendent mais *Si tu pourrais aller chercher de l'eau, ce serait cool.* est considéré comme une faute, stigmatisée comme telle.  Si bien qu'on corrigera l'enfant qui la fait, ou qu'on aura tendance à se reprendre si on la commet soi-même.

Le *si* interrogatif est suivi ou bien de l'indicatif, ou bien du conditionnel.

> - Théodule m'a demandé si Théophraste venait à la soirée.

rapporte la question

> - Théophraste vient à la soirée?

Alors que

> - Théodule m'a demandé si Théophraste viendrait à la soirée.

rapporte la question

> - Théophraste viendra à la soirée?

Comment: Merci beaucoup, donc ce qui fait l'exactitude de l'une ou l'autre formulation est le contexte, est-ce bien cela ? Mais fondamentalement, les deux formulations sont exactes.

Comment: Avec si interrogatif oui.  Sinon "si plus conditionnel" est considéré comme fautif, c'est le cas dans "Si tu pourrais aller chercher de l'eau, ce serait cool".

Comment: Parfait, dans mon contexte, la seule formulation exacte est donc la deuxième. Merci beaucoup pour cet éclaircissement précis.

Answer (score 1):

Arrêtez de vous casser la tête, retenez cette phrase :

> LES SCIES MANGENT LES RAIES

(Les SI mangent les -RAIT)
p.s. toutes les sortes de -raiT, -raiS

Quand tu as un "si" tu ne peux PAS mettre "-rait".
Sinon il va se faire manger

Comment: Excellent trucs, car en plus les poissons scies mangent d'autres espèces de raies.